# Lebesgue number lemma fails for the plane

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I need to show that Lebesgue number lemma fails for the plane. 
I am clueless how to show this.

Lemma :

> Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space. Then given an open cover $\mathcal{A}$ of $X$,  there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for each subset of $X$ having diameter less than $\delta$, there is an element of $\mathcal{A}$ containing it.

I know how to prove the Lemma , but I dont know what to do with the plane case.

Comment: For the real line, you could take an open cover consisting of overlapping intervals whose lengths tend to zero. For the plane, do something similar with annuli.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the following open cover for the plane:

$A_{1} = D_{1}$ (the open disk of radius 1 centered at (0,0))

$A_{2} = D_{2} - \overline{D}_{1 - \frac{1}{2}}$ (the open annulus that overlaps with $A_{1}$)

$A_{3} = D_{3} - \overline{D}_{2 - \frac{1}{3}}$

...

$A_{n} = D_{n} - \overline{D}_{(n-1) - \frac{1}{n}}$

You see, the area of overlap between $A_{n}$ and $A_{n+1}$ gets smaller and smaller.  Then every $\delta$ you pick will not be small enough because you can find an $N$ large enough where a ball with diameter $\delta$ with a center in the overlapping region of $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ will not be in any of the sets of the cover.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i guess it should be

$A_{n} = D_{n} - \overline{D}_{(n-1) - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}}$

So that we get decreasing area ?

Answer (score 1):

consider the following open covering of the plane:

$$\{ (-\infty, 3) \times \mathbb{R}\} \cup\{ (p_n, p_{n+2}) \times\mathbb{R}|n = 1, 2, ... \}$$

where $p_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$. There is no "Lebesgue number"
for this covering, so the Lebesgue Lemma fails.